# Scraping CSV list of urls and outputting results to different CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull urls (I've included a couple of them below) from `'YP_LA_Remodel_urls.csv` file, scrape them, then export results to `Yp_LA_Remodel_Info.csv`.

If I take one url (not from csv) and scrape it, then it works fine. It's just trying to do it on a mass scale that I'm getting hung up on. I've created my list of info that I need to extract.

I'm using script from another crawl I built, it just doesn't seem to apply to this one.  I'm a python noob, so go easy.

Any help and or suggestions are appreciated.

sample urls:

```
https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=remodeling&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=1
https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=remodeling&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=2
```

script:

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from email import encoders
import time
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import requests


def license_exists(soup):
    contents = []
    with open('YP_LA_Remodel_urls.csv','r') as csvf:
        urls = csv.reader(csvf)
        for url in urls:
            if soup(class_="next ajax-page"):
                return True
            else:
                return False

records = []
with open('YP_LA_Remodel_urls.csv') as f_input, open('Yp_LA_Remodel_Info.csv', 'w', newline='')  as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv_output_to_csv(f_output, fieldnames=[name for name, result in records])
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for url in csv_input:
        r = requests.get(url[0])        # Assume the URL is in the first column
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'info'})
        csv_output.to_csv('f_output', index=False, encoding='utf-8')


    for result in results:
        biz_name = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}) is not None else ''
        biz_phone = result.find('div', attrs={'itemprop':'telephone'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'telephone'}) is not None else ''
        biz_address = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'streetAddress'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'streetAddress'}) is not None else ''
        biz_city = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'addressLocality'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'addressLocality'}) is not None else ''
        biz_zip = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'postalCode'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'postalCode'}) is not None else ''
        records.append((biz_name, biz_phone, biz_address, biz_city, biz_zip))

df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['biz_name', 'biz_phone', 'biz_address', 'biz_city', 'biz_zip'])
```

Comment: Bet to use RegEx for scraping text files.

Comment: lot of questions.. first what is the length of csv_input... second is results a list because as per your use it doesn't seems so..

Comment: Sarthak Negi - the input will be around 10,000 urls. And i might be misunderstanding the definition of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this for two urls.. modify for 10000

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


links = ['https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=remodeling&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=1',
'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=remodeling&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=2']


container = pd.DataFrame(columns=['biz_name', 'biz_phone', 'biz_address', 'biz_city', 'biz_zip'])
pos=0
for l in links:
    soup_data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(l).content)
    results = soup_data.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'info'})
    records = []

    for result in results:
        records = []

        biz_name = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}) is not None else ''
        biz_phone = result.find('div', attrs={'itemprop':'telephone'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'telephone'}) is not None else ''
        biz_address = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'streetAddress'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'streetAddress'}) is not None else ''
        biz_city = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'addressLocality'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'addressLocality'}) is not None else ''
        biz_zip = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'postalCode'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'postalCode'}) is not None else ''
        records.append(biz_name)
        records.append(biz_phone)
        records.append(biz_address)
        records.append(biz_city)
        records.append(biz_zip)

        container.loc[pos] = records
        pos+=1
```

Output

```
                biz_name biz_phone              biz_address       biz_city  \
0                                                                              
1                                                                              
2  Washington Construction                      2874 W 8th St  Los Angeles,    
3       Os Remodeling Inc.            220 N Avenue 53 Apt 202  Los Angeles,    
4  A A Allied Construction                1212 S Longwood Ave  Los Angeles,    

  biz_zip  
0          
1          
2   90005  
3   90042  
4   90019
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: so, you're suggesting that i throw all 10,000 urls in the script instead of pulling them from a csv file?

Comment: no no that is not the point......read the csv using pandas and store the urls in a list then run the code